# What is the right scale for highly divergent values in d3 data visualization?

Tags: d3.js, data-science, data-visualization

I have two maps that plot values against counties on the United States.

Values being plotted on both are highly divergent.

On the first, around 2.5k of 3.3k counties have values of 0. While the remaining counties have values ranging up to 257,519,000.

This map visualizes just fine using `scaleLog` likeso:

```
color = d3
  .scaleLog()
  .domain(d3.max(data), d3.min(data))
  .range(["black", "purple"])
```

The next map has 0 values for about 3.2k of 3.3k counties. With the remaining c. 100 counties having values that range up to 881,587,418. The values are substantially more divergent.

Using a logarithmic scale to assign color does not work on this second map. All values are black.

***What would be the best scale to use here? Or is there another technique for plotting mostly empty, highly divergent values in D3?***

Comment: If you have 2 maps, you can have 2 color functions?

Comment: It’s really not possible to answer your question. Because the choice of scales don’t just depend on the distribution of the values but also on the intention what you want to show. There are many case where you want to show that almost all counties have a value of 0. I also don’t understand why the county with the max value doesn’t show up in purple?

Comment: If you can’t specify exactly what the ideal visualization should reveal - and that is fine - you will be able to choose the best among the tradeoffs you have to make by looking at different ones with your data. On a map you will always have to deal with the fact that different sizes of counties largely affect the perception of color coding

Comment: @ee2Dev - I'm also not sure why the max value does not show up as purple in the second map. I had just assumed it was because the distribution of the values was so broad and overwhelmingly 0 values.

Comment: Would [cartesian distortion](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) be useful here?